# Multithreadning in GNU Octave with GNU Octave code

Tags: multithreading, octave

I'm looking for a way to run a function over and over and over again by using multithreadning. Is there any way to do that in GNU Octave?

Comment: https://wiki.octave.org/Parallel_package

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you. Is there any working example I can view? Right now I only see for array functions only.

Comment: The documentation is not very complete, but here are the functions for local parallel execution: https://octave.sourceforge.io/parallel/package_doc/Local-execution.html#Local-execution -- I have no experience with these functions myself.

Comment: @euraad if you go to https://packages.octave.org and search for 'parallel' you'll see all available options. As Cris said, the `parallel` package is likely what you are looking for. There's installation instructions and documentation on that site.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I had not thought of this until now ... but I think this kind of parallelization is probably process based rather than thread based. Matlab is probably the same, no?

Comment: @Tasos In MATLAB you can make a parallel pool as process-based parallelism (where the various instances of MATLAB can each be running on a different machine in a cluster or all on the same machine), or you can configure the pool to be tread-based. The thread-based pool has more limitations about what code can run, but it avoids the inter-process communication.

Comment: @Tasos I do think Octave’s is process-based. I haven’t used this package so I’m not sure what the options are.

Comment: @CrisLuengo interesting. I was under the impression matlab was process based too. (not sure about this package either btw, I'm just guessing too)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Yes, the thread-based parallelism is more recent, and I’m sure it involves complex engineering.